# Execution order issue javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing a little issue in my jQuery script.

So, I have a function `set_fav_item` to set my item after editing it. After that is done, I want to execute another function. I don't understand why it is not working, since I do it well elsewhere in my script...

My function set_fav_item() :

```
    function set_fav_item(){

    var postid = $("#window-edit input#postid").val();
    var icon = $("#window-edit span.selected-icon > i").clone();
    var color = $("#window-edit button.jscolor").css("background-color");
    var edited_item  = $("#fav-items #"+postid+"");

    edited_item.css("background-color",color);
    icon.appendTo($("#fav-items #"+postid+" a"));

    $("#window-edit , .overlay").hide(400);

    }
```

My try :

```
    $("#window-edit #send").on("click",function(){   
    // item with id #242 is an example
    $.when(set_fav_item()).then(console.log($("#242").css('background-color')));   
    });
```

When I edit the color of my item in my edit box and click on save button (id = #send), then the console.log gives me back the old color not the new one.

If I use my browser console to check the $('#242') background color, i got the new one as expected.

Many thanks for your help.

Sommy

Comment: please share relevant html code as well.

Comment: `set_fav_item` is not returning a promise

Comment: also need to pass a function reference to `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise. A solution is to use `$.Deffered()`:

```
function set_fav_item(){

    ...
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $("#window-edit , .overlay").hide(400, def.resolve.bind(def));
    return def;
}
```

Another simpler solution is to call `.promise()` on the element:

```
function set_fav_item(){

    ...
    return $("#window-edit , .overlay").hide(400).promise();
}
```

In both cases you can do

```
 $.when(set_fav_item()).then(function(){
       console.log($("#242").css('background-color'));
 });
```

or directly

```
 set_fav_item().then(function(){
       console.log($("#242").css('background-color'));
 });
```

Comment: Thanks It Works perfectly. So, If I well understood, this is due to my hide() call ?

Comment: @donfal71 I don't understand your comment. When the callback I pass to `hide` is called, it resolves the promise, which executes the function it received in `then`.

Comment: I just meant that I had to use a promise because of my hide() function call. 

I told that because I faced this issue only in this case although I have similar sequential function calls in my script and they work without promise.

Comment: @donfal71 Yes, the `hide` function returns the element instead of a promise. But I thought of a better simpler solution, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to await for the animation to finish but they use callbacks, not promises. So you need to consider something like:

```
function set_fav_item(cb){

...;

$("#window-edit , .overlay").hide(400, function() {cb()} );

}
```

And call it

```
set_fav_item(function() {
    console.log($("#242").css('background-color')
});
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the call of `set_fav_item` , isn't it?